# "an alarm" vs "the alarm"

Tags: grammar, nouns, articles, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

Which ones correct ?

All the guests on the boat got frightened when they heard **an** alarm.

(or)

All the guests on the boat got frightened when they heard **the** alarm.

I expect the second sentence to be right because in the given scenario alarm is an definite noun. Am I right ?

Comment: Both sentences are correct.  The second is the more common.

Comment: If it was Harpo's alarm clock, it was _an_ alarm.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth What's a Harpos alarm ? Googled it too found nothing.

Comment: If it was **anybody's** alarm clock, it was _an_ alarm, unless it's already been mentioned. (Harpo Marx carried a large one on his person, on occasion.) _The_ alarm almost demands that there was a shipboard alarm / alarm signals, and this was what went off. But – there could have been personal attack alarms, an onshore ambulance, an onshore car alarm....

Comment: It depends on whether whatever was heard has an identity.  If you have established or are about to establish that it was an abandon ship alarm, say, then it's "the".   But if all we ever know is that some unidentified alarm went off it's "an".

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what kind of alarm you're speaking of. If there is some kind of random alarm which nobody much knows about, then its 'an' alarm (that is, an alarm which is not specific).

However, if you've established that something is happening, lets say — this boat of ours is sinking — then it would be 'the' alarm, since you have established context for the type of specific alarm the guest heard.

Comment: I infer from your answer that the first sentence is correct. Isn't it ? Since its just assumed to be just an another alarm.

Comment: Both are correct. However, if you are speaking of 'just ... another alarm' then the first one is correct. If you are speaking of a specific alarm, then the the second one is correct.

Answer (score 0):

> I expect the second sentence to be right because in the given scenario
>   alarm is an definite noun. Am I right ?

### Yes, you are correct

**The** second one uses a **definite** article, so a **definite** noun is **definite**ly correct to use.

There are only two articles.

`the` and `a(n)`.

`The` means your are talking about a specific alarm (one alarm).

`A(n)` means  you are talking about one of many alarms

Comment: I am having doubts since "alarm" is a countable noun "The" shouldn't  precede it .

Comment: It's either `the` or `an`.. read the update.